# Stop loop when there is an empty cell in source range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to stop a loop when there is an empty cell in source range.

For example:
My source range data is empty after "A36".
It should stop pasting of specific cell data "B9" "H9" etc. in the target sheet.
This code is still pasting data of "B9" "H9" in the target sheet.

Also how do I paste copied data in available row in the target sheet?

```vb
Sub CopyPasteValues()
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim targetRange As Range
Dim row As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim targetRow As Long

' Set the source sheet and range
Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Create Output")
Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A23:H44")

' Set the target sheet and range
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Output")
Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("A2:M2") 'start pasting after the header row

' Find the last row with data in the source range
lastRow = sourceRange.Find(What:="*", After:=sourceRange.Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row

' If there is no data in the source range, exit the subroutine
If lastRow = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

' Set the target row to the first row after the header row
targetRow = 2

' Loop through each row in the source range
For row = 1 To lastRow
    ' If there is data in the current row, copy and paste the values
    If Not IsEmpty(sourceRange.Cells(row, 1)) Then
        ' Set the values for the fixed cells (invoice no, invoice date, etc.)
        targetSheet.Range("A" & targetRow).value = sourceSheet.Range("B9").value 'invoice no
        targetSheet.Range("B" & targetRow).value = sourceSheet.Range("H9").value 'invoice date
        targetSheet.Range("C" & targetRow).value = sourceSheet.Range("C12").value 'buyer's name
        targetSheet.Range("D" & targetRow).value = sourceSheet.Range("C15").value 'buyer's address
        targetSheet.Range("E" & targetRow).value = sourceSheet.Range("G18").value 'recipe

        ' Set the values for the data cells (description, Uom, etc.)
        targetSheet.Range("F" & targetRow).value = sourceRange.Cells(row, 3).value 'description
        targetSheet.Range("G" & targetRow).value = sourceRange.Cells(row, 2).value 'Uom        targetSheet

        ' Set the values for the data cells (quantity, item rate, etc.)
        targetSheet.Range("H" & targetRow).value = sourceRange.Cells(row, 1).value 'quantity
        targetSheet.Range("I" & targetRow).value = sourceRange.Cells(row, 4).value 'item rate
        targetSheet.Range("J" & targetRow).value = sourceRange.Cells(row, 5).value 'Ex.Sale Tax Value
        targetSheet.Range("K" & targetRow).value = sourceRange.Cells(row, 6).value 'Sales Tax Rate
        targetSheet.Range("L" & targetRow).value = sourceRange.Cells(row, 7).value 'Total Sales Tax
        targetSheet.Range("M" & targetRow).value = sourceRange.Cells(row, 8).value 'TOTAL AMOUNT

        ' Increment the target row
        targetRow = targetRow + 1
    End If
Next row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in order to find the last row which contains information, you do the following:

```
' Find the last row with data in the source range
lastRow = sourceRange.End(xlDown).Row
```

Have fun!